# Django SQL Select logs - why do I see so many of them?

Tags: sql, django, performance, select, logging

I'm trying to understand how many SQL select queries each request on my app requires (Django+Tastypie). I changed the logging configuration so I can see the relevant logs.
For some reason I see a vast number of these logs.
For example, for simple get_list - I see ~100 select lines.
When I tried to debug, to see where they all come from, I couldn't step into the lines that generate these logs.
I also noticed the numbers on the left are very low (usually 0.001). I assume that this number is time to perform the query (in sec).

Any idea what's the explanation for all these lines?

Answer (score 1):

In your tastypie api.py file you probably need to change the default queryset to either include prefetch_related or select_related.  Which you use depends on your actual model.  Here's an example:

```
class OfferResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=False)
    country = fields.ForeignKey(CountryResource, 'country', full=True) 
    campaign = fields.ForeignKey(CampaignResource, 'campaign', full=False)    
    network = fields.ForeignKey(NetworkResource, 'network', full=False, null=True)       
    class Meta:
        queryset = Offer.objects.prefetch_related('offerstat').select_related('country', 'campaign', 'network').all()
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you use prefetch_related with 'offerstat', and select_related with the rest?

Comment: Uzi: 'select_related' doesn't work for reverse relationships, whereas 'prefetch_related' does: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related